# Is there a good, general description of morphisms right orthogonal to effective epimorphisms?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory

Let $C$ be a locally presentable, locally cartesian closed $\infty$-category. Then I think it's not hard to show that the class of effective epimorphisms in $C$ is closed under colimits and cobase-change, and is accessible, so that it forms the left class of a factorization system. If $C$ is an $\infty$-topos, then the corresponding right class consists of the monomorphisms in $C$. How about in general?

I guess I'm particularly interested in the case where $C$ is the unstable motivic category over a scheme $S$.